# Make Directory path with spaces in Makefile Windows Environment

Tags: windows, makefile, mkdir

I normally work in a linux environment and have Makefiles compiling my project. In the makefile it makes directories. When I use this makefile on Windows, there are spaces in the path because the User name is "John Doe".

What I've tried is:

```
MAKEPATHCMD = mkdir
build:
@( \
    echo -e "Building...\n"; \
    $(MAKEPATHCMD) "$(NEW_PATH)"; \
    .
    .
    .
```

The error is below...

```
/usr/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory '/c/Users/John Doe/Desktop/new': No such file or directory
```

Other things I've tried:

```
$(MAKEPATHCMD) "\"$(NEW_PATH)\""; \

$(MAKEPATHCMD) "'$(NEW_PATH)'"; \
```

How can I have the makefile create directory paths with spaces in them on Windows?

Comment: Can you do it on the command line, without Make? Maybe by inserting a slash or a backslash or something in front of the space? (I don't do Windows.)

Answer (score 0):

Do your work in a directory that does not contain spaces, such as c:\work.

Or, eliminate spaces in the directory name by converting it to a "short name".

Use the following script:

`rem Pass path to sanitize as arg 1
@echo off
echo Original path=[%~1]
call :chkspaces "%~1"`

if /I NOT "%_sp%" == "%~1" call :shrt "%~1"
echo uglified=[%_sp%]
goto :EOF

:chkspaces
set _sp=%1
set _sp=%_sp: =%
goto :EOF

:shrt
echo arg=[%1]
set _sp=%~s1
goto :EOF

This will produce a short name for your directory. Then just `cd` there.